# How to display custom fields of a subpages on a parent page in WP?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How would I show let's say two custom fields from the subpages on a parent page. Here's my code so far:

```
<?php
$children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0');
if ($children) { ?>
   <ul>
    <?php echo $children; ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

How would I show two custom fields with titles `details6` and `details7`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) function is what you're looking for:

```
<?php 

    // Get the page's children
    $children = get_pages("child_of=" . $post->ID);

    if (!empty($children)) { 
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($children as $child) {
            // Get the 2 meta values from the child page
            $details6 = get_post_meta($child->ID, 'details6', true); 
            $details7 = get_post_meta($child->ID, 'details7', true); 

            // Display the meta values
            echo '<li>Details 6 = ' . $details6 . ', Details 7 = ' . $details7 . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }        
?>
```

Comment: Sweet. Any idea on how to display child pages of lets say a page called "PageA" on a different page - "PageB".

Btw i got this working too. Just using a different method. See code below.

Comment: Pat, I owe you a beer for this one. Been banging my head against it all morning!

Answer (score 0):

This works too. It's probably more buggy then Pat's version.

```
    <?php
  $args = array(
'post_parent' => $post->ID,
'post_type' => 'page',
'post_status' => 'publish'
```

);
     $postslist = get_posts($args);
     foreach ($postslist as $post) :
        setup_postdata($post);
     ?>

```
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php the_permalink(); ?>
    <?php the_permalink(); ?>
    <?php echo get('details8'); ?>
    <?php echo get('details9'); ?>


    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get the page's children
$children = get_pages('child_of=' . $post->ID. '&depth=-2' );

if (!empty($children)) { 
    echo '<ul class="localPlaces">';
    foreach($children as $child) {
        // Get the 2 meta values from the child page
        $details6 = get_post_meta($child->ID, 'address 1', true); 
        $details7 = get_post_meta($child->ID, 'number', true); 
        $details8 = get_the_title($child->ID);

        // Display the meta values
        echo '<h3>'. $details8 . '</h3>';
        echo '<li>' . $details6 . ' ' . $details7 . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

This method at least shows the title of the post also